# Method to read XML file and parse it

Tags: java

How to read an XML file saved in the local folder and then use the stream object to parse it?

Answer (score 2):

You can use a `FileInputStream` (see [docs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/FileInputStream.html)).

```
File file = new File("C:\\Temp\\myxml.xml");
InputStream stream = new FileInputStream(file)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you need an URL, you can use `file.toURI().toURL()` or use a File-URL: `file://C:/Temp/myxml.xml`

Otherwise, directly go with the `FileInputStream` as suggest by Jeff.